# Does "verify email addresses?" have to be enabled in order to fire the users.onActivateUser event?

Tags: plugin-development, users

I'm trying to listen for an event when users create new accounts. I have the following code in my init() function in my main plugin class:

```php
craft()->on('users.activateUser', function(Event $event) {
    error_log("user activated");
});
```

This isn't firing when new users register on the site and I'm wondering if this has to do with the "Verify email addresses?" users setting. I'm not requiring users to verify their email addresses. Does that setting have to be checked in order to trigger that event? If so, is there a different event to listen for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onSaveUser` event instead but check for the flag inside that event called `isNewUser`

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onSaveUser

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip. That worked perfectly.